# BrightCove player Implementation in iOS

Tags: ios, brightcove

I need to implement BrightCove player in my app? How can i implement it?
I have follow this steps too.

http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/brightcove-player-sdk-for-ios/guides/quick-start.html#installation

But after "$ pod install" command i am going to run the app, it show me error.

Error is: **ld: library not found for -lPods**

[image]

Any one suggest me what to do?
Thanks,

Comment: Step by step i am following this steps. but always i will get one issue...

ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Issue Solved... Following this link.. Its good... i missed on line to read

Answer (score 0):

The simple and easiest way to implement is:

```
string url = "http://players.brightcove.net/3639471509001/bcac7227-b653-4995-9a1c-12947954823b_default/index.html?videoId=" + BrightCoveId;

WebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));
WebView.ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = false;
WebView.ScrollView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets (-30, -10, 0, 0);
```

NB: Replace the BrightCoveId with the video ID

Answer (score 0):

Once you have CocoaPods setup, you will need to open the workspace instead of the project.